# How to create stand-alone lift web application?

Tags: scala, jetty, lift

How to make a standalone lift application? Which tools/libraries to use? How does the performance compare to using lift application as a war in some application server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With onejar maven plugin http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavensite/usage.html and maven I could package jetty and project with dependencies inside one jar.

Comment: Did you not end up having issues with loading JSP files from inside of the JAR? OneJar produces nested JARs so your JSP files will end up being in JARs inside of JARs.

Answer (score 2):

The part of the question on performance doesn't really fit with the rest.  You are primarily asking how to package the Lift application as a single JAR/WAR.  This doesn't have anything to do with the runtime.

At runtime you will still be running inside a Servlet container (could be Jetty, Tomcat or a full-blown Java EE server).  How you package your application won't affect the performance.

You could take a look at [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) (a great Continuous Integration Server) to see how they deliver as a single WAR file that contains an embedded Servlet container.  You can download the WAR file and run it from the command line: `java -jar hudson.war`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but...

If you are using sbt, I wrote a plugin to produce 'executable' wars like those mentioned above.

https://github.com/glenford/sbt-jetty-embed

Comment: dead project; no activity for 3 years as of 2014.